# MySql: Update table with minimum of subset of table

Tags: mysql, sql-update, subquery

This is my test-database:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t1;
CREATE TABLE t1 (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    `parent` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL, 
    `number` int DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO t1 SET id=1, parent=NULL, number=NULL;
INSERT INTO t1 SET id=2, parent=NULL, number=NULL;
INSERT INTO t1 SET id=3, parent=NULL, number=NULL;

INSERT INTO t1 SET parent=1, number=4;
INSERT INTO t1 SET parent=1, number=2;
INSERT INTO t1 SET parent=1, number=3;

INSERT INTO t1 SET parent=2, number=10;
INSERT INTO t1 SET parent=2, number=20;
INSERT INTO t1 SET parent=2, number=30;

INSERT INTO t1 SET parent=3, number=3;
INSERT INTO t1 SET parent=3, number=2;
INSERT INTO t1 SET parent=3, number=1;
```

I'm trying to set the "number" of each parent to the minimum of the "number" of its children:

```
UPDATE t1 
SET number=(SELECT min(number) FROM t1 AS t2 WHERE t1.id=t2.parent) 
WHERE t1.parent IS NULL;
```

But this gives me an error:
ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 't1' for update in FROM clause

I understand the way would be a JOIN, but I don't get it right:

```
UPDATE t1 
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT min(t2.number) AS minnumber, t2.parent AS parent FROM t1 AS t2) t2
ON t1.id = t2.parent
SET t1.number = t2.minnumber
WHERE t1.parent IS NULL;
```

But "number" of the id1, id2, id3 is just NULL after that. I assume thats because inside the JOIN I cant restrict t2 to work only on the actual parent so it works on the whole table. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to add a `GROUP BY` clause to the inline view query (`t2`), so that it returns a row for each `parent`.

Without the `GROUP BY` clause, that query is returning a single row. (You can run just the t2 query, and see that.)

When we add the `GROUP BY` clause, we should get all the distinct values of `parent` returned, along with the minimum `number` associated with each parent.

```
SELECT MIN(t2.number) AS minnumber
     , t2.parent AS parent 
  FROM t1 t2
 GROUP BY t2.parent
```